# Slow performance for streaming videos on Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, streaming

I'm using Lubuntu 16.04 in my Samsung N210 netbook to watch some online videos, but the streaming is really bad. I'm using Firefox latest version.
Any clue if there is a way to improve that or basically I can't use the netbook for that?
Thank you.